# Phpspreadsheet using $write->save not working - error handling

Tags: php, error-handling, phpspreadsheet

I've wrote a script in a Wordpress site that sends ajax call to `functions.php` and an excel file is created.
While testing I encountered an error:
`ZipArchive::close(): Failure to create temporary file`
I realized that the file path needs to be a system path so I fixed it, in addition, my Ajax call received a response of `error 500` so I want to capture errors and send ajax the error in the response.

I have tried 2 ways:
1.

```
if( $writer->save( $file_path ) ) {
        wp_send_json( 'Success.' );
}
wp_send_json( 'Error creating report.' );
```

**[wp_send_json()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json) - Send a JSON response back to an AJAX request, and die().**

2.

```
try {
    $writer->save( $file_path );
}
catch( Exception $e ) {
    wp_send_json( 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage() );
}
wp_send_json( 'Success.' );
```

None of these methods work. What am I missing? how can I catch these errors? In order to simulate an error I input a wrong path on purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ZipArchive::close() error indicates that the permissions are wrong for the path were you want to write to.

Comment: Yes I know, my question was how to capture that error and pass it to the ajax call so I can have better user experience. Instead of server failing and script crashing I would like to present the admin with a meaningful error.
Thanks!

Comment: The $writer->save() method has no return value, that meant first method can't work. In the code on closing a zip a WriterException exception is thrown `if ($zip->close() === false) {
                throw new WriterException("Could not close zip file $pFilename.");
            }` maybe you can catch this.

Comment: I will look more into this, thank you @Sundance_Raphael